# Pods on Windows worker can't reach CoreDns

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-pod, kubernetes-networking, kubernetes-dns

I have k8s master on Debian and 2 worker nodes, linux(Debian) and windows(Server 2019).

From Pods on linux node I can ping coreDNS and I can reach services by using its DNS names. `nslookup google.pl` returns addres of google.pl

On Pods on windows worker I can't reach services by using its DNS name (by IP it's ok) and also i can't ping CoreDNS. `nslookup google.pl` returns timeout

How can I get to works this properly?

Answer (score 0):

Basically you need to troubleshoot the pod connectivity to core dns. Try telnet on core dns service IP on port 53, if that did not work, try restarting  the core dns pods (sometimes it works). check if there are any network policy applied in your cluster by doing "kubectl get networkpolicies -A", see if you have installed any cni plugins that is messing up with pod networking due to misconfigurations.